# Regarding the life of Fisher Tiger in One Piece

Tags: one-piece

I'm catching up on One Piece. I'm currently viewing the **Fishman Island** saga and more specifically, the story of **Fisher Tiger**.

***Obviously, SPOILERS ahead regarding Fisher Tiger:***

> During that story we learn that Fisher Tiger managed to climb the Red
>  Line with his bare hands (10,000 meters from the ocean surface) and
>  attack the Holy Land of Mariejois alone. A feat which shows that
>  Fisher Tiger was a man of legendary strengh.
>  
>  This is why his death was so perplexing to me. After reaturning Koala
>  to her parents he was attacked by Rear Admiral Strawberry and a score
>  (?) of marines. He was shot to death. 
>  
>  How this can be? How can such a powerful warrior die of a score of
>  mare marines and a Rear Admiral when he managed to attack and survive
>  Mariejois?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, most of the guys in one piece are vulnerable to bullets, unless they have a capacity to prevent that (evading/countering bullets, logia fruits, luffy's gum gum) especially if they are haki bullets (as all vice admirals have haki, and strawberry is one of them)

Comment: Yeah, I get that but I imagine that invading Mariejois must mean that you will get shot hundreds (if not thousands) of times. It doesn't make sense to me that one can survive something like that and not survive being ambushed by a score of marines.

Comment: It seems to me that Mariejois was not that heavily armed, if at all. I don't think they were well prepared to defend against an attack, and therefore the risk of getting shot was relatively low compared to a wall of trained marines.

Comment: Isn't he still lives after that incident? He doesn't shot to death, he survives, but deadly injured, and he refuse to get donor from human blood, so he died.

Answer (score 1):

First, climbing a mountain couple thousand meters high isn't a big performance in the one-piece world. Luffy climbed a 3000m (~9000 feet) high mountain covered in ice and snow when he was on the drum island before the timeskip (Before getting stronger).

Second, Mariejois is the land of the descendents of the gods, the celestial dragon's. Celestial dragons hate every kind of person who's beneath them, even marines, so it's probably not very armed, Marines only use it as way to the New World and they still need to wait months to get access.

> The Holy Land Mariejois (聖地マリージョア Seichi Marījoa?) is the capital of the World Government and **functions as the primary path which individuals seeking to enter the other, far more tumultuous and dangerous side of the Grand Line, the New World, pass through**.

And third, Fisher Tiger only attacked the home of the celestial dragons, where the biggest defence are the slaves.

Comment: I also think that Fisher Tiger had a (slight) advantage because he knew the layout of Mariejois since he has been a slave himself. Knowing when and where to strike can influence the outcome of his actions greatly.